# Manipulating the DOM only after Svelte child nodes have all updated

Tags: svelte

I have a Svelte component that does an `#each` on its child components. However, after all of the children are updated I want the parent to adjust the position of the children to align with the content they refer to. (Think: comments in a Google Doc.) It’s not possible for a child to know its own position when the child is rendering because I need to handle overlaps: if two child components refer to the same content I need to spread them out vertically so they're readable. That needs to be handled by the parent. Is there a preferred way to handle something like this? I was thinking the child components could register their DOM nodes to the parent `onMount` and the parent could position in its `afterUpdate`. Ideas?

Here’s a [rough vanilla DOM/JavaScript demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-cloud-08lez) to kinda sorta illustrate what I’m trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for the cross-post on Discord. I’m going to stick with Stackoverflow from now on for design questions.

Comment: This is exactly what `afterUpdate` (and `bind:this`) is for, yep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sharing DOM nodes with the parent, you can use data binding.

The "content" component could share it's `offsetTop` with the parent. The "comment group" component would share it's `height`.

Then the parent would have the data it needs to compute the offset of each "comment group".

The parent would need to decide whether the alignment should be vertical middle or vertical top (you might need to align to vertical top, if the previous "comment group" had a larger height than the content it referred to)

Comment: I don’t think the location of the children can only be determined after the parent and all of the children are sized. Thus, I think I’ll need a higher-level component that can coördinate.

Comment: With several more days of Svelte under my belt, this answer makes more sense now. “Use data binding” should have been my first clue. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using tick lifecycle method, https://svelte.dev/tutorial/tick

Comment: I didn’t see that. Thanks for the heads-up. It looks super useful for batching updates in a single component. However, unless I’m missing something, I don’t think it helps coördination across components. Am I misreading?